# In R Shiny App, how to render a default table when first invoking the App?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, render, shiny-reactivity

The below MWE code works fine, EXCEPT that when first invoking the App, the default table does not render in the sidebar panel as it should.

The default table only renders after clicking the "Modify" action button in that sidebar panel. Prior to clicking the "Modify" action button, I get the following error message in the sidebar panel: "is.matrix(value) is not TRUE".

So how do I get the default table to correctly render upon invoking the App?

Note that after clicking the "Modify" action button and making any changes to the matrix input grid that pops up in the modal dialogue box, those changes are instantly reflected in the table that appears in the sidebar panel, and those changes "stick" when the user dismisses the modal dialogue and clicks on "Modify" again. This is an important feature that works well.

Yes, I posted a similar question on Aug 24 for a somewhat more complex section of code but I'm having trouble implementing it into this example. I've tried implementing this solution via:

```
df <- if(is.null(input$modify)){df >- NULL}
          else{input$matrix3}
```

in the below MWE code, and in other spots including inside `reactiveValues`, but with no luck yet. Hopefully if someone guides me through this solution one more time, it'll "stick" with me!

After figuring this out, I'll post the corrected code asking exactly what is it in the reactivity chain that allows modifications to the matrix input grid to stick from one click of the "Modify" action button through to the next click. I'm trying to repeat this feature in another section of code.

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

# Function assigns row headers to input matrix grid
  matrix3Headers <- function(){c('A','B','C','D')}

# Assigns default values to first column of input matrix grid
  matrix3Default <- matrix(c(1,24,0,100),4,1,dimnames=list(matrix3Headers(),NULL))

# Automatically assigns names to column headers
  colnames(matrix3Default) <- paste0("Series ",1:ncol(matrix3Default))

# Matrix input function
  matrix3Input <- function(x, matrix3Default){
    matrixInput(x,
                label =  'Input series terms into below grid:',
                value =  matrix3Default, 
                rows  =  list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE), 
                cols  =  list(extend=TRUE,names=TRUE,editableNames=FALSE,delete=TRUE),
                class =  'numeric'
      ) # close matrix input
  } # close function

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    titlePanel('Inputs'),
    fluidRow(actionButton('modify','Modify'),tableOutput('table2'))
  ) # close fluid page

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
          mat3=matrix3Input('matrix3',matrix3Default),
          input=matrix3Default,
          colHeader = colnames(input)
        ) # close reactive values
  
  observeEvent(input$modify,{
    showModal(modalDialog(
      rv$mat3,
    )) # close shown modal and modal dialog
  }) # close observe event
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3)
    
    df <- if(is.null(input$modify)){df >- NULL}
          else{input$matrix3}
    
    n <- dim(df)[2]
    rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
    
    rv$input <- df
    colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
    df},rownames=TRUE, colnames=TRUE) # close output$table1
  
  } # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `NULL` value in `renderTable` so that the code runs only when `input$matrix3` is present. Apart from that you can simplify the logic further so that the code runs only when `!is.null(input$modify)`

```
matrix3Headers <- function(){c('A','B','C','D')}

# Assigns default values to first column of input matrix grid
matrix3Default <- matrix(c(1,24,0,100),4,1,dimnames=list(matrix3Headers(),NULL))

# Automatically assigns names to column headers
colnames(matrix3Default) <- paste0("Series ",1:ncol(matrix3Default))

# Matrix input function
matrix3Input <- function(x, matrix3Default){
  matrixInput(x,
              label =  'Input series terms into below grid:',
              value =  matrix3Default, 
              rows  =  list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE), 
              cols  =  list(extend=TRUE,names=TRUE,editableNames=FALSE,delete=TRUE),
              class =  'numeric'
  ) # close matrix input
} # close function

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel('Inputs'),
  fluidRow(actionButton('modify','Modify'),
           tableOutput('table2'))
) # close fluid page

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    mat3=matrix3Input('matrix3',matrix3Default),
    input=matrix3Default,
    colHeader = colnames(input)
  ) # close reactive values
  
  observeEvent(input$modify,{
    showModal(modalDialog(
      rv$mat3
    )) # close shown modal and modal dialog
  }) # close observe event
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(input$matrix3)) return(matrix3Default)
    rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3)
    
    df <- input$matrix3
    if(!is.null(input$modify)) {
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
      
      rv$input <- df
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
    }
    df
  }, colnames=TRUE) # close output$table1
  
} # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

*PS - `>-` is not a valid operator in R.*

Comment: Hi Ronak, all clear. However how do I modify this so the default table appears in the sidebar pànel when first invoking the App? Currently, it only appears after clicking the "Modify" action button.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `matrix3Input()` before testing if the `input$modify` exists so you get the error `is.matrix(value) is not TRUE` because the `input$matrix3` does not exist yet.

If you move your test before calling the `matrix3Input()` function, your `is.null(input$modify)` is always `FALSE`, you must use the `isTruthy()` function to test inputs in Shiny. Check the values you are testing with the `print()` function, e.g. `print(is.null(input$modify)`.

Here's a working example:

```
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    
    if(!isTruthy(input$modify)){df <- matrix3Default}
    else{
    req(input$matrix3)
    rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3)
    df <- input$matrix3
    n <- dim(df)[2]
    rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
    
    rv$input <- df
    colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
    
    }
    df
    },rownames=TRUE, colnames=TRUE) # close output$table2
```

This example shows the matrix with the default values taken from `matrix3Default` (as you ask in the title), just replace `df <- matrix3Default` by `df <- NULL` if you want no initial display of the table.

Comment: Hi julien.leroux5, thank you for this. Works well and your explanations are very helpful as I'm "learning". However, when running this I get the following message in the R Studio console: "Warning: Error in matrixInput: is.matrix(value) is not TRUE...". Do you know how to eliminate this?

Comment: Ah yes, because when creating the `rv` expression, the `reactiveValues` function calls the `matrix3Input()` function and again the `input$matrix3` is not present. Just replace `df <- rv$input` by `df <- matrix3Default` (as I edited my answer).

Comment: Same error appeared when clicking the button, so I also added a `req(input$matrix3)` line so it's waiting for this input to be present.