# In R Shiny, how to eliminate "Warning: Error in if: argument is of length 0" from running reactive function?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In running the below MWE code, in the R studio console box I get the warning "Error in if: argument is of length 0" though the App actually continues running fine. What am I doing wrong? How do I eliminate this?

Here's how the App works. As shown in the first image below, the user can vary the periods Y in the slider and the base value level Z in the input box that appears in the sidebar panel. Base value derived from `matrix1...` in MWE. As shown in the 2nd image, the user can make further alterations to variables Y and Z, including altering Z value curve shape, by clicking on "Show" action button and making changes to the matrix input grid that pops up. This second matrix grid is derived from `matrix2` and as you can see, these 2 matrices are linked with `matrix2` superseding `matrix1`. (Note: make any matrix input changes first to the right column, then the left column; this is due to a minor bug in shinyMatrix that I need to download a fix for).

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)
    
matrix1Input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 1, 1, dimnames = list(c("Z"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

matrix2Input <- function(x,y,z){ # x = label, y = period, z = value in period y
  matrixInput(x,
              value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}  

matrixLink <- function(x,y){
  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,x,value=matrix(c(input$periods,y),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL, c("y","z"))))
  })} # close observe event and function

matrixValidate <- function(x,y){ # x = time period x, y = matrix inputs
  a <- y                                
  a[,1][a[,1]>x] <- x                   
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])           
  b[b<=0] <- NA                         
  b <- c(1,b)                           
  a <- cbind(a,b)                       
  a <- na.omit(a)                       
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]             
  return(a)}

# --- Spreads matrix1 input across even time horizon of periods x --- #
vectorBase <- function(x,y){ # x = periods, y = value to spread over periods x
  a <- rep(y,x)                         
  b <- seq(1:x)                         
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)         
  return(c)}

# --- Interpolates & spreads matrix2 input across even time horizon --- #
vectorMulti <- function(x,y,z){ # x = total periods, y = period, z = value to apply in period y                                            
  a <- rep(NA, x)                                                     
  a[y] <- z                                                           
  a[seq_len(min(y)-1)] <- a[min(y)]                                   
  if(max(y) < x){a[seq(max(y)+1, x, 1)] <- 0}                         
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y    
  b <- seq(1:x)                                                       
  c <- data.frame(x=b,z=a)                                            
  return(c)}

# --- Runs vectorMulti raw inputs through matrixValidate to output clean vector data --- #
vectorMultiFinal <- function(x,y){ # x = periods, y = matrix input
  vectorMulti(x,matrixValidate(x,y)[,1],matrixValidate(x,y)[,2])}

vectorPlot <- function(w,x,y,z){plot(w,main=x,xlab=y,ylab=z)}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Model..."),
  sidebarPanel(uiOutput("Panels")), 
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Balances", value=2,
                 fluidRow(
                   radioButtons(
                     inputId = 'Tab2',
                     label = h5(strong(helpText("View:"))),
                     choices = c('Vector plot'),
                     selected = 'Vector plot',
                     inline = TRUE
                   ) # close radio buttons
                 ), # close fluid row
                 conditionalPanel(condition="input.Tab2=='Vector plot'",plotOutput("graph1")),
      ),  # close tab panel
      id = "tabselected"
    ) # close tabset panel
  ) # close main panel
) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  periods      <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input   <- reactive(input$base_input)
  yield_input  <- reactive(input$yield_input)
  showResults  <- reactiveValues()

  vectorVariable <- function(x,y){
    if(input$showVectorBtn == 0) vectorBase(input$periods,x)
    else vectorMultiFinal(input$periods,matrixValidate(input$periods,y))}  
  
  yield <- function(){vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],yield_input())}

  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==2",
        sliderInput('periods','Periods Y:',min=1,max=30,value=15),
        helpText(strong('Change variable Z below:')),
        matrix1Input("base_input"),
        useShinyjs(),
        helpText(strong('Add curve to variable Z:')),
        actionButton('showVectorBtn','Show'), 
        actionButton('hideVectorBtn','Hide'),
        actionButton('resetVectorBtn','Reset'),
        hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))
      ), # close conditional panel
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  renderUI({matrixLink("yield_input",input$base_input[1,1])}) 
  
  vectorsAll <- reactive({cbind(Period = 1:periods(),Yld_Rate = yield()[,2])})
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorBtn,{shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideVectorBtn,{shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{showResults$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")},ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetVectorBtn
    matrix2Input("yield_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1])
  }) # close render UI
  
  output$graph1 <-renderPlot(vectorPlot(yield(),"","Period","Rate"))
  
  output$showResults <- renderUI({showResults$showme})
  
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: need `matrixInput` function too

Comment: Hi Pork Chop, matrixInput is part of the shinyMatrix package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by reviewing similar post  [In R Shiny App, how to render a default table when first invoking the App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68962409/in-r-shiny-app-how-to-render-a-default-table-when-first-invoking-the-app) and with mnist's explanation: error occurs in `vectorVariable()` because when the app starts, this function is evaluated before `input$showVectorBtn` is created hence this value is NULL. I inserted the following default values to help with rendering a plot with when first invoking the App: `matrix2Default <- vectorBase(15,0.2)`, and I replaced the `yield <-` function in the original MWE with the following tests for where things stand with user inputs:

```
 yield <- function(){
if(!isTruthy(input$base_input)){matrix2Default} else {
  if(!isTruthy(input$showVectorBtn)){vectorBase(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1])} else{
    vectorVariable(yield_input())
    } # close second else
  } # closes first else
} # close function
```

As mnist states, the code and functions are very convoluted. There are some irrelevant pieces of code in the original MWE, representing vestiges from the original code this MWE was stripped from. I will be working to simplify this code!

Below is complete working MWE that resolves the issue. Note that custom functions aren't repeated below as they are the same as in original post, EXCEPT don't forget to include the new `matrix2Default` function!!

```
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Model..."),
  sidebarPanel(uiOutput("Panels")), 
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Balances", value=2,
               fluidRow(
                 radioButtons(
                   inputId = 'Tab2',
                   label = h5(strong(helpText("View:"))),
                   choices = c('Vector plot'),
                   selected = 'Vector plot',
                   inline = TRUE
                 ) # close radio buttons
               ), # close fluid row
               conditionalPanel(condition="input.Tab2=='Vector plot'",plotOutput("graph1")),
      ),  # close tab panel
      id = "tabselected"
    ) # close tabset panel
  ) # close main panel
) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  periods      <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input   <- reactive(input$base_input)
  yield_input  <- reactive(input$yield_input)

  vectorVariable <- function(y){vectorMultiFinal(input$periods,matrixValidate(input$periods,y))}
  
  yield <- function(){
    if(!isTruthy(input$base_input)){matrix2Default} else {
      if(!isTruthy(input$showVectorBtn)){vectorBase(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1])} else{
        vectorVariable(yield_input())
        } # close second else
      } # closes first else
    } # close function
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==2",
        useShinyjs(),
        sliderInput('periods','Periods X:',min=1,max=30,value=15),
        helpText(strong('Change variable Y below:')),
        matrix1Input("base_input"),
        helpText(strong('Add curve to variable Y:')),
        actionButton('showVectorBtn','Show matrix below'), 
        actionButton('hideVectorBtn','Hide below matrix'),
        actionButton('resetVectorBtn','Reset below inputs'),
        hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))
      ), # close conditional panel
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorBtn,{shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideVectorBtn,{shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})

  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetVectorBtn
    matrix2Input("yield_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1])
  }) # close render UI
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot({vectorPlot(yield(),"","Period","Rate")})
  
}) # close server
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs in `vectorVariable()`. when the app starts, the function is evaluated before `input$showVectorBtn` is created, hence this value is `NULL` and the error is shown. after `conditionalPanel()` is run, the test works.

You could avoid this issue by including some `req()` in your `renderPlot()` which stops evaluation if its input is not truthy (see ?shiny::req). However, there might be some logical drawbacks of this solution so make sure to test your application carefully.

```
  output$graph1 <-renderPlot({
    req(input$showVectorBtn)
    vectorPlot(yield(),"","Period","Rate")
    })
```

##### Some additional notes

Your code is a bit convoluted and error-prone. try not to write functions that use objects from their parent environment but provide everything through function arguments.

Comment: How do I show the plot before "Show" action button is clicked? With the plot reactive to any changes to Y and Z before clicking on "Show"?

Comment: Also mnist, I am fairly new to all this. What is the difference between "functions that use objects from their parent environment" versus "providing everything through function arguments"?